# IOException File too large, while downloading gradle on mac while running react-native run-android command

Tags: android, macos, react-native

I am in the process of setting up my development environment for react-native android development.

I have already followed all the steps as mentioned in installation guide :
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

I am getting the following exception while executing
`npx react-native run-android`

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:14406) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 1426 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
debug Running command "cd android && ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081"
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
..
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: File too large
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:98)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:63)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

React native version :react-native-cli: 2.0.1 react-native: 0.63.2
macOS version 11.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was the OS which was complaining that the file is too big. There is a limit on the size of files created by the shell. We can run this command :
`ulimit -f 2097152` to set the limit to 2 GB (2097152 kB = 2 GB). This solved the problem for me.